# How to solve the error syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'?

Tags: opencart

i have code. but I can not understand why he swears?

This is line 17

```
 if (!empty($city_result = $this->model_module_novapochta->getCity($this->request->post['novaposhta_key']))) {

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /home/s2332/***.com/www/admin/controller/shipping/novaposhta.php on line 17**

if (!empty($this->request->post['refresh']) && !empty($this->request->post['novaposhta_key'])) {
            if (!empty($city_result = $this->model_module_novapochta->getCity($this->request->post['novaposhta_key']))) {
                $this->session->data['error'] = $city_result;
            } elseif (!empty($address_result = $this->model_module_novapochta->getAdress($this->request->post['novaposhta_key']))) {
                $this->session->data['error'] = $address_result;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is wrong...
You have write:

```
if (!empty($city_result = $this->model_module_novapochta->getCity($this->request->post['novaposhta_key']))) {
```

must be:

```
$city_result = $this->model_module_novapochta->getCity($this->request->post['novaposhta_key']);
    if (!empty($city_result)) {
//your code here
```